# How to append every true if, else if statement to a text file?

Tags: java

How do I append every user chosen equation in an `if`, `else if` statement to a text file. I am not sure where would the best place be to put the append to file because putting it in under every `else if` statement seems repetitive.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javaCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);

        double number1;
        double number2;
        String operator;

       
        System.out.print("Enter the operator you would like to choose(+, -, *, /): ");
        operator = operation.next();

        
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(numbers.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(numbers.nextLine());


        
        if (operator.equals("+")){
            String calculation = (number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + (number1 + number2));

        }else if (operator.equals("-")){
            String calculation = (number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + (number1 - number2));

        }else if (operator.equals("*")){
            String calculation = (number1 + " * " + number2 + " = " + (number1 * number2));

        }else if (operator.equals("/")){
            String calculation = (number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + (number1 / number2));

        }else{
            String calculation = (operator + ":" + " Is not a valid operator!");

        }
        try {
            Formatter file1 = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\27711\\Desktop\\PROGRAMMING\\java\\JavaCalculator");
            file1.format(calculation);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Attempting to use a variable when it isn't in scope
- The way you're writing to a file using `Formatter`

## Making the calculation variable available

All you need to do is declare your `calculation` variable *once*, before the `if/else` statements:

```java
String calculation;

if (operator.equals("+")) {
    calculation = number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + (number1 + number2);
} else if (operator.equals("-")) {
    calculation = number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + (number1 - number2);
} else if (operator.equals("*")) {
    String calculation = number1 + " * " + number2 + " = " + (number1 * number2);
} else if (operator.equals("/")) {
    calculation = number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + (number1 / number2);
} else {
    calculation = operator + ":" + " Is not a valid operator!";
}
// Code to append to the file
```

In your current code, you're declaring a *different* variable in each `if/else` block, which means no `calculation` variable is in scope by the time you reach the file appending code.

An alternative approach would be to use a conditional operator. Some folks really don't like multiple uses like this, but I personally think it ends up being very readable:

```java
String calculation =
    operator.equals("+") ? number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + (number1 + number2)
  : operator.equals("-") ? number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + (number1 - number2)
  : operator.equals("*") ? number1 + " * " + number2 + " = " + (number1 * number2)
  : operator.equals("/") ? number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + (number1 / number2)
  : operator + ":" + " Is not a valid operator!";
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider a switch statement, maybe in a whole separate method:

```java
private static String calculate(String operator, double number1, double number2) {
    switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            return number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + (number1 + number2);
        case "-":
            return number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + (number1 - number2);
        case "*":
            return number1 + " * " + number2 + " = " + (number1 * number2);
        case "/":
            return number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + (number1 / number2);
        default:
            return operator + ":" + " Is not a valid operator!"
    }
}
```

... or a [switch expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) if you're using a recent version of the language.

## Writing to the file

The [documentation for `Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) starts:

> An interpreter for printf-style format strings.

While you *can* use a `Formatter` to write to a file, you don't want to interpret printf-style format strings at all... and you're currently not closing the formatter, either.

I'd suggest using the `Files` class instead. You can just write:

```java
Files.write(Paths.get(filename), Arrays.asList(calculation));
```

To append, you can pass in `StandardOpenOptions.APPEND`:

```java
Files.write(
    // Where to write...
    Paths.get(filename),
    // The lines to write...
    Arrays.asList(calculation),
    // How to open the file...
    StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the part below that is not working since OP expects the `Formatter` to write something to a file.

Comment: @f1sh: Aha... I'll address that part separately.

Comment: @f1sh: Looking at the documentation for Formatter, that actually seems reasonable. But the OP isn't closing the formatter, and they don't *really* want to be dealing with a format string...